# Connecting topics to one 2 d list in R

Tags: r, nlp

I am trying to attach all topic columns to one column in R - just combine all sentences into one huge sentence.

I have tried following code and it isn't giving desired output:

```
for (b in 1:3) {(for (a in 3:25){olc<-c(vector,ola[b,a])})}
View(olc)
```

And I am getting following error:

**Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1**

I have attached the table of the main file:

[image]

Desired output would be a list with all the dates and a combined topic column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want the entries from each row "Top1", "Top2", "Top3" to be combined in one entry, or if you just want them stacked on top of each other. 
In the first case, you can probably do something like this:

```
df.new<- data.frame(Date = df$Date, Label = df$Label, 
                Topic = with(df, paste(Top1, Top2, Top3, sep = " ")))
# or whatever else you want the separator to be, i.e. sep = "," or sep = "-"
```

In the second case, you could try:

```
df.new<- melt(df, id.vars = c("Date", "Label"))
```

***UPDATE:***
Maybe you can try something like this:

```
df.new2<- cbind(df$Date, df$Label, apply(df[,c("Top1", "Top2", "Top3")], 1,
                                         function(x) list(x)))
colnames(df.new2)<- c("Date", "Label", "Topics")
```

Note, this is now a matrix. If you want to access the topics, you'll have to do `df.new2[,"Topics"]`.

***2nd UPDATE:***

```
Topics<- split(df[,c("Top1", "Top2", "Top3")], df$Date)
names(Topics) # this will give you the dates
```

Also, please try to post a small part of your data (not an image) and an example of a preferred output, so that it's easier to work with.

Comment: sorry this didn't work out, even a 2d list will work if not a data frame.

Error: Arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1